# Не возможно зайти в phpmyadmin - Denwer

Tags: denwer

Я недавно начал работать с денвером.
И у меня ошибка при входе в `phpmyadmin` после того, как я удалил всех пользователей.

Comment: Самый лучший вариант - не использовать устаревший denwer вообще и перейти на OpenServer.

Comment: Поддерживаю предыдущий комментарий. Переходите на OpenServer. Он активно поддерживется и развивается по сравнению с денвером